# Detect Python Is Running In Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

There are cases where code needs to act differently if running in Visual Studio Code.

Does anybody know the most efficient way to detect that the python code is running in the Visual Studio Code debugger?

So far, the best way I could find was using:

```py
import sys
if 'debugpy' in sys.modules:
    print("Running in VS Code")
```

Comment: What are you trying to differentiate it from? What's the end goal? My first thought would be with a command line variable like `python myscript.py --vscode`

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/); it may be that you don't need to do this at all. We have no idea why you need to do this, not that we need to know, but it could end up that you don't need to do it if we knew more about why.

Comment: The behavior in VS Code sometimes differs from running code from  command line. For instance, I just discovered a bug on Linux where VS code escapes single quotes in args on Linux but does not do this on Windows.

Comment: @Timothy C. Quinn Hi, have you submitted this issue on GitHub?

Comment: Yes - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18926. It went in as 'feature' as the bug reporting tool was having issues for me. Waiting for someone to change tags.

Answer (score 2):

On vscode the environment variable `TERM_PROGRAM` is set to 'vscode', you can check it by:

```py
import os
if 'TERM_PROGRAM' in os.environ.keys() and os.environ['TERM_PROGRAM'] == 'vscode':
    print("Running in VS Code")
```

Comment: Good catch Eran! Confirmed on Linux and Windohs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most elegant way to solve this is just to set up a run task in vscode that runs the Python script with an extra command line flag.

for example:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--vscode', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.vscode:
    print("vscode")
else:
    print("not vscode")
```

then if you call the script `python myscript.py`

> 'not vscode'

if you call `python myscript.py --vscode`

> 'vscode'

Then you can just add a run task in vscode:

```
{
    "label": "run",
    "command": "python", // or python3
    "group": {
        "kind": "test",
        "isDefault": true
    },
    "args": [
        "${file}",
        "--vscode"
    ],
    "presentation": {
        "echo": true,
        "panel": "shared",
        "focus": true
    },
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```

To run your code, just use a shortcut for your run task

Answer (score 0):

Although I think that @Eran's answer feels the most succinct, here is another method:

```
if ('debugpy' in sys.modules \
       and sys.modules['debugpy'].__file__.find('/.vscode/extensions/') > -1):
    print("Running in VS Code")
```

This detects `debugpy` and prevents false positive if another tool uses the same `debugpy` namespace.